# Hearing the sentence "ねんね横髑髏二つ"

Tags: listening

I'm a Japanese beginner who just started immersion listening. At 2m8s of [this anime](https://animelon.com/video/5762abf7fc68e08dcd850d84), the following line is spoken:

> ねんね横髑髏二つ？

**Omission of 横?** I don't hear the word "横" （よこ） spoken in this line. Am I mistaken? If not, is it fairly common for Japanese shows to transcribe words that aren't actually spoken into their subtitles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term from the Death Note manga is 横{ねんね}髑髏{どくろ}.

Probably the original JP subs had furigana on 横 (due to ねんね not being a normal reading of that kanji), and the pirated version of the anime episode linked in your question had some issue when ripping furigana, so both the kanji and furigana ended up in-line.

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of "ねんね" in this context? And is is the "ねんね" reading of 横 something that could be looked up in any dictionary, or is this show just imbuing a custom reading of a Kanji for stylistic purposes (is that common in Japanese)?

Comment: @George It seems to be a creative reading, presumably inspired ねんね～寝る～横になる=to lie down. So it should mean a skull that lies down (= does not sit up straight). [Same hinative q&a](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/15925835).

Comment: (And yes that is quite common and is called [義訓{ぎくん}](https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/義訓#現代の義訓))